# how get email of logged in users by yahoo

Tags: yahoo-api

I read [this article](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/openid-oauth-guide.html)

I don't understand that after I get the access token, by what endpoint can I get the email address of the logged in user?

---

my steps:

1- send user to yahoo login page:

```
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&response_type=code
```

2- after confirm yahoo redirect user to my redirect_uri with code parameter

3- I take received code and make a POST connection to yahoo and send code to it and yahoo give me the access token:

```
$postdata = array(
        'grant_type'=>'authorization_code',
        'code'=>$_GET['code'],
        'redirect_uri'=>'{redirect_uri}'
);

$header = array('Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode({client_id}.':'.{client_secret}));

curl("https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token","POST",$postdata,$header);
```

5- after that I make a GET connection to yahoo to give logined user profile:

```
$header = array('Authorization: Bearer {access_token}');
curl('https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/me/profile?format=json',"GET",array(),$header);
```

there isn't user email in response:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["profile"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (25) {
    ["guid"]=>
    string(26) "3KFOKEMJXONWVU2HNL3EAKQNIQ"
    ["ageCategory"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["birthYear"]=>
    int(1990)
    ["created"]=>
    string(20) "2011-03-05T11:12:04Z"
    ["displayAge"]=>
    int(25)
    ["followMode"]=>
    string(5) "ALLOW"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "M"
    ["image"]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (4) {
      ["height"]=>
      int(192)
      ["imageUrl"]=>
      string(56) "https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/social/profile/profile_b192.png"
      ["size"]=>
      string(7) "192x192"
      ["width"]=>
      int(192)
    }
    ["intl"]=>
    string(2) "us"
    ["jurisdiction"]=>
    string(2) "us"
    ["lang"]=>
    string(5) "en-US"
    ["memberSince"]=>
    string(20) "2011-03-05T11:11:42Z"
    ["migrationSource"]=>
    int(1)
    ["nickname"]=>
    string(12) "Saeid Ezzati"
    ["nux"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["profileMode"]=>
    string(6) "PUBLIC"
    ["profileStatus"]=>
    string(6) "ACTIVE"
    ["profileUrl"]=>
    string(51) "http://profile.yahoo.com/3KFOKEMJXONWVU2HNL3EAKQNIQ"
    ["searchable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["updated"]=>
    string(20) "2015-06-22T10:23:38Z"
    ["isConnected"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["profileHidden"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["profilePermission"]=>
    string(7) "PRIVATE"
    ["uri"]=>
    string(71) "https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/3KFOKEMJXONWVU2HNL3EAKQNIQ/profile"
    ["cache"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] detailing the code you have tried. Explain why it does not work for you and what the expected results are.

Comment: @Adriaan I added my code